# unable to increase sga_max_size. MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system error

Tags: oracle12c

I am using Oracle DB version 12. DB server has a RAM of 59gb. sga_max_size value was set to 30gb. When I try to increase it more than 30gb, I am getting 'MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system' error. 
So what can be the max 'sga_max_size' value that can be set for a server with RAM Xgb.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS used is Linux, you likely need to increase /dev/shm:

```
$ oerr ora 845
00845, 00000, "MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system"
// *Cause: The MEMORY_TARGET parameter was not supported on this operating system or /dev/shm was not sized correctly on Linux.
// *Action: Refer to documentation for a list of supported operating systems. Or, size /dev/shm to be at least the SGA_MAX_SIZE on each Oracle instance running on the system.
```